# error deploying JSF application through netbeans

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I had to re-install netbeans on my OS and when opening project I had a **data source error**  I solved this issue and my project does not show any other errors but when deploying I get the following error message

```
Starting GlassFish Server 4.1
GlassFish Server 4.1 is running.
In-place deployment at D:\ALL-ESTEBANS-BACKUP\NETBEANS-WORKSPACE\Nomad\build\web
GlassFish Server 4.1, deploy, null, false
D:\ALL-ESTEBANS-BACKUP\NETBEANS-WORKSPACE\Nomad\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1060: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 21 seconds)
```

looking at the server log:

```
The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:259)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:166)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.ant.Deploy.execute(Deploy.java:111)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
INFO [glassfish]: GlassFish configuration file C:\Users\esteban\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\config\GF_4.1\domain1\config\domain.xml was modified, updating server configuration.
```

I have no idea what this could mean and I've been searching with no luck.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only shooting in the dark : Did you change the server port number using the GlassFish admin GUI tool? It is not automatically reflected in the NetBeans IDE in most versions. Moreover, try cleaning the osgi cache along with the "generated" folder in the server to see, if it is helpful (stop and start the server afresh).

Comment: @Tiny, No I didn't change the server port number. All I did in the GF UI Admin tool was  set the  **Jndi**.